# How can I set Google Inbox to handle mailto: on El Capitan?

Tags: mailto

I expect Inbox to open when I click on a link like this:

```
mailto:john@example.com
```

Comment: You use the link `http://mailto://example.com`, which is not a valid mailto link. It should be `mailto:john@example.com`. And apparently that doesn't work as link here.

Comment: IIRC, Chrome can do that. No idea how to get it back once you declined, though.